# Audio/video Programming

Tags: iphone, macos, ffmpeg

I want to access Audio and video into my program. Is it possible to do in MAC.

Our Program is working on Windows here i did audio/video programming using directshow. but i want to develop same in MAC.

Is there any package same like directshow. Please give some valuable tips.

Answer (score 2):

Register for the regular (not iPad/iPhone) OS X developer program at developer.apple.com, download and install XCode tools, and then start reading the documentation for the CoreAudio and Quicktime APIs. You will quickly gain momentum.

Comment: Can u suggest any starter material or any link

Comment: The XCode tools bundle of course contains a nice GCC/GDB IDE and Interface Builder. A less advertised feature is a fairly complete library of examples to illustrate all the major families of APIs that ship with OS X. The developer website contains lots of well structured documentation -- not just API docs but manuals. Reading those docs is really the place to start. Just keep a close eye on those examples that you received along with XCode.

Comment: As an alternative, you can always consider the Java APIs for sound, video capture, and video playback. The best way to learn these, IMHO, is to start at processing.org, a nice rapid prototyping environment for Java multimedia applications. You can do a lot with very little code.

Comment: Nice to read ur post...
My need is to take 8 audio channels from pic using pci card and using this audio in my project.
Same times its accessing camera for video.